# Выборка из таблицы с интервалом времени

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица, с такими полями (пишу только необходимые): `user_id`, `ticket_id`, `close_day`, `status`. Все поля типа integer. `close_day` хранит метку времени.

Нужено составить запрос, который бы возвращал сумму `ticket_id`, где `status`>0 с начала года. Группировать результат нужно по `user_id` с интервалом в 1 месяц.

Возможно ли это сделать одним запросом? А то раньше с интервалами мне не приходилось сталкиваться...

**UPDATE:**

Наваял сам. Делает то, что хотелось. Может кому пригодится для примера:

```
SELECT
  `user_id`
  ,count(`ticket_id`) as sum_closed
  ,DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`close_day`), '%m') as month
FROM
  `support_tickets`
WHERE
  `status`>0
  AND `close_day`>UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2011-01-01 00:00')
  AND `t_date_close`<UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2012-01-01 00:00')
GROUP BY month,`userid`
ORDER BY `close_day`
```

Comment: Наверное все-таки не сумму `ticket_id`, а количество? зачем суммировать айдишники?

Comment: Да, верно, количество

Comment: ну собственно заменить `DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`close_day`), '%m') ` на `month(close_day)` и будет мой вариант. Только у вас не очень корректно учтено условие "с начала года". В следующем году придется переписывать )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тогда все элементарно.

```
select 
  user_id,
  month(close_day),
  count(1)
from
  tickets
where 
  `status` > 0
  and year(close_day) = year(now())
group by 
  user_id,
  month(close_day)
```

Выбираем идентификатор пользователя, месяц года и кол-во тикетов, где статус ненулевой и год равен текущему году с группировкой по пользователю и месяцу.

Comment: За ответ спасибо кстати. Не знал что есть столь гибкая работа с временем в MySQL

Comment: ну что тут сказать, RTFM: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month

Comment: Что-то не хочет. Я так подозреваю, что что-то с форматом времени. Даже если сделать просто `SELECT month(close_day) from tickets`, то возвращает массив с количеством элементов равным количество строк в базе и значениями NULL.

Comment: А у вас `close_day` точно TIMESTAMP? У меня на пробном наборе данных, все ок.

Comment: ну если только они не отличаются в mysql и php. В табличке значения времени сохраняются функцией time() (PHP)

Comment: Да, все верно, поле то integer, потому надо просто month(FROM_UNIXTIME(`close_day`)) . Еще раз спасибо! Ответ принят!

Answer (score 1):

Написать запрос на основе только текущей таблицы можно. Но он будет во первых очень громоздким, во вторых не целесообразным по скорости работы так как на базу будут накладываться лишние вычисления. Поэтому я вижу 2 варианта:

1)
создается дополнительная таблица в которой будет
month_id, month_start, month_finish
где 
month_id - уникальный идентификатор месяца.
month_start  - метка времени начала месяца
month_finish - метка времени конца месяца

и тогда запрос будет вида

```
SELECT `user`.`user_id`, count(*) as `count` 
FROM `month`, `user` 
WHERE `user`.`status` > 0 
AND (`user`.`close_day`>=`month`.`month_start` OR `user`.`close_day`<=`month`.`month_finish`) 
ORDER BY `user`.`user_id`, `month`.`month_id`
```

Это если вы хотите 1 запросом.

2)

```
SELECT `user_id`, `close_day` FROM `user` WHERE `status` > 0
```

а дальше с помощью foreach() перебрать массив который получился в результате и привести к нужному виду.

Comment: Спасибо, за помощь, но решение нашел сам, без доп.таблицы одним запросом.

Comment: Можно его сюда? Интересно.